# Can't make specific part of content stop overflowing its container and become scrollable

Tags: html, css, containers, overflow

After two month of learning to code I've decided to code a simple bug-tracker on my own with no code-along videos. Managed to do a JS-part, but now I am really stuck on the problem of div overflowing its container and its quite a specific one.

[Here is an image of result I've got.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UaFAC.png)

I'll leave html and css samples down.

Add task shows modal and creates a card. Cards are always firstly added to backlog section and can be dragged between columns.
As I create more then two cards with tasks they overflow their container. I planned tbody "#task-list" to be scrollable, but not the whole body or container. I've tried limiting every container's height - it still overflows. I've tried adding "overflow: scroll" onto tbody "#task-list" and on its child tr - no effect, nothing changed. It stops to overflow only if I add "overflow: scroll" onto "#task-list" tr td div. But then I get scrollbar on every column, which is not what I wanted. What is the reason I cant make content of tbody "#task-list" stay in container and be scrollable?

```
<main class="main">
            <side class="sidebar">
                <div class="main-tabs">
                    <div class="overview">Overview</div>
                    <div class="my-tasks">My Tasks</div>
                    <div class="projects">My Projects</div>
                    <div class="reports">Reports</div>
                </div>
                <div class="technical-tabs">
                    <div class="settings">Settings</div>
                    <div class="logout">Log out</div>
                </div>
            </side>
            <div class="content" >
                <div class="project-name">Project Name</div>
                <div>Add a Task</div>
                <button id="add-btn" class="add-task">+</button>
                <table class="tracker-board" id="overview">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Backlog</th>
                            <th>To Do</th>
                            <th>In Progress</th>
                            <th>Done</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody id="task-list">
                        <tr>
                            <td id="backlog-list"><div class = "card-holder empty"></div></td>
                            <td><div class="empty"></div></td>
                            <td><div class="empty"></div></td>
                            <td><div class="empty"></div></td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </main>
```

The div with class "card-holder" gets another div ".card" when task is created.

```
/* Main Content */
.main {
    background-color: #fff;
    color: var(--secondary-color);
    width: 90%;
    max-height: 800px;
    margin: 20px auto;
    border-radius:20px;
    display: grid;
    grid-area: main;
    grid-template-areas:
        "side tracker";
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 5fr;
}

/* Tracker Window */
.content {
    grid-area: tracker;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    gap: 12px;
    height: 600px;
}

.content > div {
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: 600;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.add-task {
    width: 80px;
    padding: 3px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    font-weight: 700;
    background: var(--primary-color);
    color: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: 30px;
}

.tracker-board {
    height: 500px;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
}

.tracker-board #task-list {
    height: 100%;
    font-size: 20px;
}

#task-list > tr {
    height: 600px;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
}

thead th{
    font-size: 24px;
    border-bottom: var(--secondary-color) solid 2px;
    max-width: 250px;
}

tr > td {
    padding: 0;
    width: 260px;
}

td .empty {
    height: 100%;
}


#task-list td > div {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    flex: 1 0 250px;
}

.card-holder {
    height: 100%;

}

.card {
    margin:15px;
    border: var(--secondary-color) 2px solid;
    color: var(--secondary-color);
    border-radius: 20px;
    box-shadow: -5px 10px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: 500;
    max-width: 250px;
}
```

I'll be grateful if you point out any other mistakes I made as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can try to separate the header and contents of the table into different entities (create different tables for the two).

Comment: Yes, it behaves almost as I wanted to, but it still scrolls the whole section. Idea was to be able to scroll only the table body. But somehow if I add  ```overflow:scroll``` on table or any of its children or grandchildren - it doesn't affect anything.

Comment: You can try adding it to the table body.

Comment: That what I thought as well. Firstly I added it to table body. Didn't work. After that I added scroll style to table body's child tr. But somehow in these both cases cards just keep overflowing its containers, as it can be seen on image I added.

Comment: So creating two separate tables for head and body brought up a problem of not matching head and body column width (which is minor problem). But still as I tried to add overflow: scroll to new table or it's child (tbody) or grandchild (trow) - it still doesn't change anything.